# URL Rewrite causing redirected you too many times

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am using IIS url rewrite rule to redirect from an IP Address to a domain name with the following rule.

```
<rule name="IPHit" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="10.32.1.132" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Unfortunately, this results in an infinite loop redirect when I go to https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas.

How can I redirect from the IP address without having an infinite loop on dns entry?

Comment: Please use FRT to dig further, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules One guess is that your network devices somehow modified the requests to use Host header of an IP address instead of `daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com` (default value by most web browsers). If that's the case, work with your network engineering team to fix that, or use other conditions to stop redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will redirect 10.32.1.132/eds-daas to https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas/eds-daas. Is that expected behavior?

May I know your only face this infinite loop when you access specific URL or all requests hitted by IP address. What loop URL did you see in web browser developer tool?
Post the symtptom of loop URL would help us find the root cause.

[image]

Or you need to redirect request 10.32.1.132/eds-daas to https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas? If so you may need two rules side by side.

```
  <rule name="IPHit" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="10.32.1.132" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/eds-daas(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>

                <rule name="IP-HIT2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="10.32.1.132" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/eds-daas(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://daart-qa.sandbox.aimsplatform.com/eds-daas{C:1}" />
                </rule>
```